# how copy database from assets to ExternalStorage?

Tags: android

I want copy a database
 from the assets folder to my phone memory card .
When the program is run ..
the program is stop..

This message shows  in logCat:
java.lang.NullPointerException...
I'm confused ..
I do not know what's the problem
The assets folder
 There is a file named "home.db"
please help me..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    File f1=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"aaa");
    f1.mkdir();

    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        in = getBaseContext().getAssets().open("home");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OutputStream ou = null;
    try {
        ou = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"aaa"+ "/"+"home" );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        CopyDB(in, ou);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void CopyDB(InputStream in, OutputStream ou) throws IOException
{
    byte []buffer=new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length=in.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        try {
            ou.write(buffer, 0, length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    in.close();
    ou.close();


}
```

}

Comment: Where is your NPE? Mind posting your stack trace?

Comment: Agreed. Stack trace would be very useful to see.

Comment: Now what should I do?
Sorry my English is not so good ?

Answer (score 0):

> There is a file named "home.db"

And yet you are doing

```
in = getBaseContext().getAssets().open("home");
```

So `in` remains null as the IOException is catched.

Try this :

```
in = getBaseContext().getAssets().open("home.db");
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help u sure 
Also don't forget   to give  permission - -  accessexternal storage